# How to check if object is ready to use in template Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a custom class that I initialize in constructor of Angular component:

```
public constructor() {
    this.custom = new Custom();
}
```

In template I use this instance `this.custom` like:

```
<div>{{custom.count()}}</div>
```

Problem is, sometimes object `this.custom` is not ready, so it can not find method `count()` inside.

How to check this in template?

I tried:

```
<div ngif="custom.count()"></div>
```

Comment: That's not your issue. Objects that are instanciated are usable. Please post a [mcve] reproducing your issue on stackblitz.

Comment: ```<div>{{custom?.count()}}</div>```

Comment: Also, I don't really think it is recommended to make a function call in the string interpolation syntax (`{{...}}`) as it can cost a lot of performance. To verify this, just place a `console.log` in the `count` method and check the console for the number of logs it prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?.`:

```
<div>{{custom?.count()}}</div>
```

Or show the element conditionally with `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="!!custom">{{custom.count()}}</div>
```

Comment: What about  `*ngIf="custom"`

Comment: Safe operator does not work in this case: `{{unconfirmedScoresTree?.summary?.count()}}`

Comment: I used `!!custom` to make sure that the value is evaluated as a boolean.

Comment: What if I will move initialization in ngInit instead constructor: `this.custom = new Custom();`?

Comment: You can also initialize it when you declare it `public custom = new Custom();`. However, I don't know if the variable is reset (to `null` or `undefined`) later during execution. My two suggestions will work in all cases.

Comment: By the way, the `?.` navigator should also work for multiple levels. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cxrsh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).